# Should I be rendering html on the server-side or client-side?

Tags: templates, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am looking into Backbone JS and getting a little confused. I am used to compiling my page html on the server-side ([using JADE](http://jade-lang.com)) and then interacting with these elements using jQuery on the client-side. A lot of the backbone examples suggest starting from a blank html body and rendering content on the client-side.

This seems really strange to me!

**Questions:**

1. Do I have to use client-side templating?
2. Can I use BackboneJS to control pre-written server-side compiled html?

Comment: Both. You support non-javascript browsers and offload work to clients with javascript whenever possible

Comment: I think it depends on what your building -- for a blog, it'd make sense to do all the rendering server-side (unless you want to get into all that [hashbang crap](http://dannythorpe.com/2011/02/09/side-effects-of-hash-bang-urls/)). For an app, I'd take the pragmatic, hybrid approach that Brian suggests: bootstrap the expected information into the page that the server serves, then update the view using Backbone's AJAX facilities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The typical way of using Backbone is to do things client-side.  You use client-side template rendering to bind model values to your small view templates.  It is an approach to turning HTML/JS into a application development platform with an actual component model.

**BUT, that doesn't mean that you can't or shouldn't mix your worlds.**

For example, I use Backbone with Rails.  My Rails view renders server-side HTML which includes Backbone logic/views.  Then, all of my AJAX-style view rendering happens using Backbone with models, views and templates and the models talk to JSON services that live in the Rails backend.  The user doesn't see a page load until they need to leave the page to do something else.  The experience is quite nice.

You can certainly take that example and render your templates server-side.  I wouldn't go as far as to render every instance of the template server-side because templating engines (including the one built into Backbone/Underscore) are so powerful.  But, if you wanted to seed your templates with server-side rendering, I could see how that might be useful.

Comment: Would it make sense to render the core static parts of my app using JADE on the server-side and then render the dynamic parts of my app using backbone on the client-side?

Comment: @pagewil Yes.  That is a nice, concise way of saying what I was trying to say.  You _can_ write an app without any server-side rendering using Backbone.  Most people, from what I understand, take a hybrid approach like what you are suggesting.

Comment: fwiw: backbone relies on jquery quite heavily, so you're still going to work the same way that you have been. the difference is that you'll be wrapping your jquery code inside of a few backbone constructs. i wrote a blog post on doing this, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

Comment: the thing with node.js is that you can use _the exact same_ templates on client and server therefore doing both is _free_.

Comment: @Raynos I've been using JADE on the back-end but haven't seen anyone template with JADE and back-bone. Was thinking the jQuery template plugin looked nice and simple.

Comment: @pagewil Have you looked at the templating engine that Backbone ships with? (from Underscore).  It is simple and powerful enough to do everything I need.  It seems like you could use Underscore in Node.js and re-use the templates like Raynos suggested but I fear you'd lose that ability if you went to the jQuery templating plugin.

Comment: @pagewil The problem of using the _same_ templating engine on client and server is not an easy problem. My solution is to write my own templating language. I personally know that dust, jQuery-tmpl and underscore.template will work on both.

Comment: @BrianGenisio [node-jqtpl](https://github.com/kof/node-jqtpl). You can punch express so that it renders jQuery templates. i don't know _why_ you would want to do this. (jqtpl really isn't that good an engine). Also underscore.template is just not flexible enough for a server-side templating system.

Comment: For reusing templates on client and server in Rails, I have had good experience with the Poirot gem.  https://github.com/theworkerant/poirot